# Hibernate bidirectional association removal

Tags: hibernate, jpa, associations, spring-data-jpa, bidirectional

I am using hibernate and Spring to persist data in database, (just to be sure I've tested with MySQL and MSSQL) and I am facing a strange behaviour, I'm mapping my classes this is way:

```
    public class User extends BaseDomain implements UserDetails {
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
        private List<UserRole> userRole;
            ... 
    }
```

Child Entity:

```
public class UserRole extends BaseDomain implements GrantedAuthority {
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
    private Role role;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
... 
}
```

At this point if I try to remove an user, it is ok:

```
Hibernate: delete from user_role where id=?
Hibernate: delete from user where id=?
```

However, my problem begins when I add the second parent class:

```
public class Role extends BaseDomain {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "role", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<UserRole> userRole;
...
}
```

From now on, hibernate only delete the parent (User) entity, causing an exception. 
Any guess on what's wrong with my mapping?
Thanks in advance.
OBS: Every other DB operation works fine. I also try Set<>.

**UPDATE**

If let my second Parent class mapped like in the below way, it works, however, now I am unable to delete the child from the `Role` side, is there a way to keep the same behaviour in both sides?

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "perfil", orphanRemoval = true)
private List<UserRole> userRole;
```

Comment: What happens if you remove orphanRemoval from the Role entity? Do the userRole entries get deleted when you delete a user?

Comment: No, still not work, thanks for your reply.